# How to find the paths to the directories which contains jni.h and jni_md.h?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am a Windows user. I have a code in C and another in Java. I am trying to compile and link, however, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: program10.convert(D)D
at program10.convert(Native Method)
at program10.printTable(program10.java:65)
at program10.main(program10.java:16)
```

I tried these two:

```
gcc -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191/include/ -I/usr/java/jdk1.                                                                                                        8.0_191/include/win32 -shared -o libprogram10.so program10.o
    
gcc -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/ -I/usr/java/jdk1.                                                                                                        8.0_131/include/win32 -shared -o libprogram10.so program10.o
```

On my computer, the location is: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\include`

Here is my code:
program10.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program10 {
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("program10");
    }

    public native double convert(double f);
    /*code here*/
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*code here*/
}

public int interface() {
    /*code here*/
}

public void printTable(int size) {
    /*code here*/
}
```

program10.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "program10.h"
    
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_program10_convert(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdouble n) {
    /*code here*/
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking about `jni.h`, which is a file used at *compile-time*, when the error you get is a **runtime** error?

Comment: *"I am a Windows user and I am using Unix"* --- So which is it? Windows or Unix? The `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\include` path would indicate Windows, but please **edit** the question and clarify what operating system you're doing this on.

Comment: @Andreas because I don't know where the error comes from. And I thought it could be because I did not find the path correctly.

Comment: It comes from the JVM when it cannot find the `convert` method in the `program10.dll` (Windows) / `program10.so` (Linux) file.

Comment: ```gcc -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/ -I/usr/java/jdk1.                                                                                      8.0_131/include/win32 [...]``` <- the ***/win32*** part seems fishy if you run this command on Linux